# Jna property setting

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, jna

i have the following applet:

```
public class FakeApp extends PApplet{
    public PApplet father;
    int numPixels;
    int[] backgroundPixels;
    Capture video;

    Display d;

public void init(){
    super.init();
    this.setup();
}
public void setup() {
    super.setup();
      size(640, 480); 
      d=new display();
      d.setup((PApplet)this);  
}
public void draw(){
    d.draw();
}
```

}

where Display is delegated to show camera input:

```
public void setup(PApplet father) {
    this.father=father;

  // This the default video input, see the GettingStartedCapture 
  // example if it creates an error
  video = new Capture(father, 640, 480);
  //video = new Capture(father, father.width, father.height);

  // Start capturing the images from the camera
  video.start();  

  numPixels = 640* 480;//video.width * video.height;
  // Create array to store the background image
  backgroundPixels = new int[numPixels];
  // Make the pixels[] array available for direct manipulation
  father.loadPixels();
}

public void draw() {
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read(); // Read a new video frame
    video.loadPixels()  ; // Make the pixels of video available

 // Difference between the current frame and the stored background
    int presenceSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { // For each pixel in the video frame...
      // Fetch the current color in that location, and also the color
      // of the background in that spot
      int currColor = video.pixels[i];
      int bkgdColor = backgroundPixels[i];
      // Extract the red, green, and blue components of the current pixel's color
      int currR = (currColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
      int currG = (currColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
      int currB = currColor & 0xFF;
      // Extract the red, green, and blue components of the background pixel's color
      int bkgdR = (bkgdColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
      int bkgdG = (bkgdColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
      int bkgdB = bkgdColor & 0xFF;
      // Compute the difference of the red, green, and blue values
      int diffR = father.abs(currR - bkgdR);
      int diffG = father.abs(currG - bkgdG);
      int diffB = father.abs(currB - bkgdB);
      // Add these differences to the running tally
      presenceSum += diffR + diffG + diffB;
      // Render the difference image to the screen
      father.pixels[i] = father.color(diffR, diffG, diffB);
      // The following line does the same thing much faster, but is more technical
      //pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | (diffR << 16) | (diffG << 8) | diffB;
    }
    father.updatePixels(); // Notify that the pixels[] array has changed
    //father.println(presenceSum); // Print out the total amount of movement
  }
}

// When a key is pressed, capture the background image into the backgroundPixels
// buffer, by copying each of the current frame's pixels into it.
public void keyPressed() {
  video.loadPixels();
  father.arraycopy(video.pixels, backgroundPixels);
}`enter code here`
}
```

running this PApplet as an applet actually works, and also the following:

public class FakeStart {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
    f.setLayout(null);
    FakeApp app=new FakeApp();
    app.init();
    //app.size(500, 500);
    //app.setup();
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.show();
    f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    );
    f.add(app);
    app.show();
}
```

}

works fine. the problem is that the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    aaa.view.video.FakeStart.main(null);
```

}

fails with:

```
(javaw.exe:5620): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/aaa/dskV/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstwavparse.dll': `C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/aaa/dskV/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstwavparse.dll': Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

+30 similar warnings, and the camera fails to load.
(the path C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/aaa/dskV/video/library/\windows64\plugins\ is correct)

So in short:

-when i run the code as an applet it works.

-when i launch a main that opens the applet in a jframe it works (if the main is in the dskV project where the native code is).

-when i launch a 1 line main that invokes the working main it doesnt work (in this case the main is in the root project).

-the dskV project has all the libraries required to make the native code work(and in fact it works), the root project has the dskV project in its build path. and to make sure also has all the libraries of dskV (tested with them and without, im desperate). i tried both

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/aaa/dskV/video/library/windows64/plugins/" );
```

and

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/aaa/dskRoot/video/library/windows64/plugins/" ); after copying the natives in the root project.
```

in all possible places.

what can be this jna starting project related issue?

Comment: `library/\windows64` I'm not sure this /\ is causing the problem, but regardless, it doesn't look good, I would try to get rid of that as the first thing.

Comment: hi, the library that access the native code is a 3rd party jar, i cant really modify that. I tryed to rename the directory and the previously working cases did stop to work, also i tested and the adress with the /\ is correctly computed in the right dir.

Comment: `jna.library.path` only affects loading of the first module explicitly loaded.  Any dependent libraries must be found either in the same directory as the first one loaded, or on %PATH%.

Comment: mhhh could be that the jna.library.path is set in the library utilizing "user.dir" that depends on the launching project? i tried immediatly afrer startup System.setProperty("user.dir","C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\bbb\\gg_dskV"); but no luck